# configure dns host records for https without subdomain

Tags: dns

`http://example.com` resolves to my web host properly - Azure.

`https://www.example.com` resolves to my web host as expected.

`https://example.com` is unexpectedly resolving to my domain registrar DNS host - NameCheap.

I want the latter to end up resolving to the web host.

How can I configure my domain registrar to also pass along the request to my web host when **using the https scheme without a subdomain**?

When browsing to `https://example.com`, of course it resolves to an IP that's not serving

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 68.65.123.196:443

This IP address belongs to my DNS host.

Answer (score 1):

At issue is that the "A" record for your the base domain name (example.com) is pointing to the correct place.   The solution is to get this added to your zone file.

As you are using a cloud based service its probable that the "www.example.com" record is pointed to the cloud using a CNAME - and best practice dictates you don't use a CNAME for a base domain name, as it acts in non-intuitive ways - thus you are limited to adding an A record for it - and this A record can break if the IP address of the target changes - where the CNAME for the subdomain will remain in tact as the provider can update the A record the CNAME points to.

So the short answer which is 95% correct is "you can't easily and reliably do this unless your cloud provided can guarantee you a specific address" (You can do a hack like get an additional certificate, static IP address and set up a redirect - but that probably defeats the purpose of cloud hosting).

Answer (score 0):

DNS translates FQDNs to IP addresses - it does not have any say over http vs. https.

What you need is for your hosting provider to enable https for your website.

Comment: `https://www.example.com` resolves to my web host as expected.